# Перегрузка метода в Google Test

Tags: c++, google-mock, google-test

В моём TestMock классе у меня есть два метода:

1. `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(function1, const bool&());`
2. `MOCK_METHOD0(function1, bool&());`

В тестовой фикстуре я хочу вызвать второй мок, но тест вызывает первый мок.

```
    EXPECT_CALL(*testMock, function1());
```

Что я должен сделать, чтобы в `EXPECT_CALL` вызывался второй мок?

```
class TestA
{
public:
    virtual ~ TestA() {}
    bool foo1()
    {
        return function1();
    }
    virtual bool& function1() = 0;
    virtual const bool& function1() const = 0;
};


class TestMock : public TestA
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(function1, const bool&());
    MOCK_METHOD0(function1, bool&());
    virtual ~ TestMock () {}

};
class TestConfiguration : public :: testing :: Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {


    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        delete testMock;
    }

public:
TestMock *testMock;
};
TEST_F(TestConfiguration, testFooTEST)
{
    testMock = new TestMock();

    EXPECT_CALL(*testMock, function1());

    testMock->foo1();
}
```

Comment: В  классе  TestConfiguration    { //... public:  using TestMock::MOCK_METHOD0 //...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPECT_CALL` ничего не вызывает, это макрос служит для регистрации ожиданий вызова, т.е. написав такую строчку `EXPECT_CALL(*testMock, function1());`, Вы говорите: «до конца этого теста на объекте `*testMock` должен произойти вызов `function1`». Если условие не соблюдено, то получите ошибку.

GMock различает перегруженные методы и для Вашего случая тоже имеет решение. По умолчанию, в такой перегрузке GMock будет ожидать вызов неконстантного метода, чтобы указать ему, что нужно ждать вызов константного метода нужно написать так: `EXPECT_CALL(Const(*testMock), function1());`